# actionscript 2 panning

Tags: actionscript-2

please could someone help me please as have just started using actionscript and really don't know much about it

basically it's a panning thing where a user clicks on a link and the contents of that page scroll onto the screen

I have used this code which is for AS3 but wondering how i could get it to work with AS2

And no this is not a class project

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;

import fl.transitions.easing.*;



home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,panContent);

about_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,panContent);

contact_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,panContent);



function panContent(evt:MouseEvent){

var buttonName:String = evt.target.name;

switch(buttonName){

case "home_btn":

new Tween(content_mc,"x",Strong.easeOut,content_mc.x,0,1,true);

break;

case "about_btn":

new Tween(content_mc,"x",Strong.easeOut,content_mc.x,-2048,1,true);

break;

case "contact_btn":

new Tween(content_mc,"x",Strong.easeOut,content_mc.x,-4096,1,true);

break;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated:

```
import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;

    home_btn.onPress = function(){
var home:Tween = new Tween(content_mc, "_x", Regular.easeOut, content_mc._x, 0, 3, true);
    }

    about_btn.onPress = function(){
var about:Tween = new Tween(content_mc, "_x", Regular.easeOut, content_mc._x, -2048, 3, true);
    }

    contact_btn.onPress = function(){
var contact:Tween = new Tween(content_mc, "_x", Regular.easeOut, content_mc._x, -4096, 3, true);
    }
```

Comment: hi thanks for that but i can't download the file and forgot to say I'm using flash cs5

Comment: If this is the case i've edited the code for default transitions

Comment: hi i have tried your code but it won't pan left or right so am i missing something and sorry for being a pain

Comment: please provide the fla files for further assistance

Comment: hi sorry never used stack overflow before how do you had a file sorry for asking a dumb question like that

Comment: I couldn't open the file because it's 5.5
Here is a demo of it working http://www.mediafire.com/?7eba7zd76x878t7

Comment: oh damn sorry i keep forgetting is cs5.5 that's old age setting in for you LOL i have looked at yours and that is exactly what i was looking for thank you so much for you help miro i really really appreciate all your help

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad I was helpful. You can click the Check Mark on my answer to mark it as answered.